# Is runApp() method necessary to create a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform

[dart code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiqiL.png)

> I expected this code to paint a black colored rectangle to screen but it didn't .I'm using flutter framework and I want to know that don't flutter support making apps like these or any mistake in my code. I just
> wanted to make run flutter code without built-in flutter framework library

}

Comment: yes is necessary runApp() method to create app

Comment: Your `main()` method must contain `runApp(MyApp())`. `MyApp` must be a Stateful or Stateless widget which must return a `MaterialApp` Widget

Comment: no, `runApp` is not necessary, check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/2783f8e2e14efec8b7e08f668dde61c40d128c24/examples/layers, it shows 4 different layers, try 2 first: `raw` and `rendering`

Comment: Thanks the link cleared my doubt

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's necessary. In dart only execute code inside the main method. Not like JavaScript or Python. It's like java/c. The only execution is the main method.